# How to get @Assisted annotation in play framework

Tags: playframework

Im trying to get the @Assisted annotation in a play project. Is there any lines i should add to build.sbt to get it?

Comment: Add some more details. Of what library this annotation is part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build.sbt project has to be modified.

Following library dependency should be added in to it.

```
"com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-assistedinject" % "3.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your other question I'm assuming that you want to add Guice to your project. You need to add the library to your build definition in the `build.sbt` file.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "4.0-beta5"
```

Read more about dependency management in the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies).